# See load balancers health check status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am using a reverse proxy in front of my load balancer. Currently I am just trying to make a TCP connection with LB from reverse proxy to check its health and if it succeeds then I will send the request to main load balancer. I want to check that whether my main load balancer have any servers running or not. If not I want to redirect those requests to another server fleet. Is there api or anything else which AWS load balancer exposes to tell the status of the its targets.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the EC2 console, and then to the target groups section. Select your target group. From there, you should be able to see which instances are passing the healthcheck.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).